# COUNTIFS events between dates but also time

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, timestamp

For reporting I export raw data from a pbx in CSV. There are many columns with data. Relevant for this case is:

- Column A: Date of the events (there are many events on a same day)
- Column B: Length of the events in seconds
- Column C: Date + Timestamp of every event

I filter out all events shorter or equal to 90 seconds,

I am able to adjust the range by changing dates in 2 cells I created for this occasion (start date is in D1 & end date is in cell D2). Without integarting time I use:

**=COUNTIFS(B:B;">=90";A:A;">="&D1;A:A;"=<"&D2)**

It works like a charm. I select a range in cells D1 & D2 and I automatically get all the events between these dates excluding events shorter or = to 90 sec.

**On top of this I need to know how many events / occurrences happen between certain timestamps. For example from November 1st till November 7th I need to know how man events happened between 12:00h and 13:00h, how many happened between 15:00h & 18:00h etc.**

Logically I thought that just adding another *criteria_range* and *criteria* (in this example column C) would do the trick. Alas adding column C does not seem to work and I have spinned it many ways.

My intuition is that the **DATE + TIME format** is inadequate, innapropriate for my case.

**Column C looks like this: 02/11/2015  21:59:47**

Being european, I'm happy with the DD/MM/YYY notation, but it seems that no formula can take account of the TIME and neglect the DATE in front. Remember I already use column A for the dates. Here in column C I am interested in the TIMESTAMP.

Any aideas or suggestions are welcome.

Thank you very much in advance.

**PS:** I can always split the time from the date using text to column feature. Yet It means I will be formatting the raw exports and I would like to avoid that at all costs so that I can just copy paste new exports in my control sheet without having to do all sorts of formatting.

Comment: When you say *'Length of the events in seconds'*, do you mean that column B is elapsed time in seconds or that column B has integers representing the elapsed seconds?

Comment: Is Column `C` text or numeric?

Comment: @EEM selecting a unique cell in column C excel says it is a date. I didn't format it as such though. It seems excel recognises it as a date.

Comment: @Jeeped Currently working on your proposal. Will let you know if I can make it work, seems you nailed it. Thanks for the input anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without sample data it is difficult to tell whether you are treating the elapsed time as `90` seconds (integer) or `00:01:30` (as true seconds, a decimal portion of 1). Your formula seems to indicate the elapsed time as an integer but it is also wrong in other places (e.g. `=<` instead of `<=`) so the only thing for certain is that it is  not a working formula. The same goes for determining the time window. Are you comparing it to `12` and `13` as integers or `12:00:00` and `13:00:00` as true time? They are decidedly NOT the same thing.

The [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) can provide the cyclic processing required to treat a datetime as time only (e.g. `MOD(C2:C12, 1)`) or as an integer representing the hour of the day (e.g. `HOUR(C$2:C$12)`).

[image: TIME over COUNTIFS]

The formulas in F2, F5 and F7 are,

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B; ">="&E2; A:A; ">="&E3; A:A; "<="&E4)
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$12>=E$3)*(A$2:A$12<=E$4)*(MOD(C$2:C$12; 1)>=E5)*(MOD(C$2:C$12; 1)<=E6)*(B$2:B$12>=E$2))
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$12>=E$3)*(A$2:A$12<=E$4)*(MOD(C$2:C$12; 1)>=E7)*(MOD(C$2:C$12; 1)<=E8)*(B$2:B$12>=E$2))
```

If E5 and E6 were `12` and `13` instead of `12:00:00` and `13:00:00` then the formula in F5 would be,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$12>=E$3)*(A$2:A$12<=E$4)*(HOUR(C$2:C$12)>=E5)*(HOUR(C$2:C$12)<=E6)*(B$2:B$12>=E$2))
```

Comment: Maybe interesting for you to know: 1st of all it works like a charm. Thank you very much for that (I know I am not advised to say this but I was struggling with this for some hours and I'm damn happy you solved this issue for me!) 

But I use 13:00:00, ex: 24/09/2015  13:57:43; yet the MOD version did the trick, not the HOUR variant. 

Anyhow. Problem solved.

Comment: Provide some several rows of sample  data or a link to a redacted workbook.